# USB devices not detected if connected on the fly

Tags: usb-drive

I am facing a weird issue now. If I try to connect any USB device while in the middle of a session randomly, chances are, the USB device will not be recognized. If I reboot the whole system with the USB device still connected, it works fine after the reboot is complete.

Initially I thought this was something random. But now this happens all the time. It is starting to get very annoying. I have searched for this but haven't found any reports of the same kind. There have been reports of USB not getting recognized entirely but none of them apply to my scenario as the devices in question start working without a problem after a restart. Why is that? I don't know where to start debugging this. Can anyone help?

I am running ElementaryOS Freya on a Lenovo G50 laptop.

The output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:6513 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0101:0007  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited: I am pretty sure that you have it sorted out now. However, just in case...FYI My issue was sorted out with some help from @Jorge R Marin as you can see in the following link.
[TLP Power Management disables USB devices in my ASUS UX305 ultrabook. Needs restart!](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/tlp-power-management-disables-usb-devices-in-my-asus-ux305-ultrabook-needs-rest/9313?noredirect=1#comment12358_9313)

Before Edit:Has your problem been solved. I am facing the same issue! This is in addition to printing and screen issues (Running Loki on Asus UX305 (Dual Boot option). Out of the box, the notebook came with windows 10 home). But this one seems to be a deal breaker.

To detect the device, I have to do either of the folowing: a) suspend the system and wake it up (b) turn off the computer and restart. This issue is observed whether I use the USB-3 or USB-2 ports.

Would appreciate if you let me know how you solved this problem.

output of sudo lsusb Before And After device insertion:

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b56b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Prathap

Comment: Hi! taking cue from another post, I just removed the TLP power management software. Now, the pendrives are recognized without any issue.

Comment: However, I see that the battery juice is draining faster than before. So, if you have a solution that allows you to keep the TLP and yet allows th emachine to recognize the USB devices, please let me know.