# No USB when already logged

Tags: release-loki, usb-drive, mount

I have an amazing problem (that's why we love eOS !).

If I plug an USB in my laptop, He don't reconize it (in lsusb too).
If I plug an USB BEFORE loggin, it's reconized (only once, if I eject my USB I must relog to mount it again).
Of course, it's not a hardware problem.

What I can do ?

Comment: Do you have TLP or another Power Management tool installed?

Comment: oh, yes I have TLP. I will try to desactivate it.

Comment: You can keep using TLP just configure USB in TLP  http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9313/6398

Comment: Without TLP it's work ! I'm confused. Thank you.